# Detect mouse scroll in console application

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to write a C++ program which will act as a feeder of a virtual joystick http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/.
I now successfully use the mouse cursor position to feed X and Y axis. Now I want to use the mouse wheel to feed the Z axis. But I tried of finding the way to detect the scroll. Can anyone suggest me on this? I use MinGW compiler.

By the way, this is my code : http://pastebin.com/WuFV8X3h

Comment: You need to intercept [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645614(v=vs.85).aspx) message

Comment: I came across this solution for a while, can you give me an introduction to event programming? I can't understand it.

Comment: I'll return to you in a couple of hours.